# Photos sort with jquery sortable, not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm sorting out my photos with jquery sortable plugins. If you have 10 shipment the sorting is working properly. But when there are more than 10 photos, the sorting is not working properly.

My photos

```
<div class="sortable">
<div id="rank-1" class="multibox file">
  <div class="picture_delete"></div>
  <img src="../../images/gallery/thumb/1.jpg" style="cursor: move;" class="picture_uploaded">
  </div>
<div id="rank-2" class="multibox file">
    <div class="picture_delete"></div>
    <img src="../../images/gallery/thumb/2.jpg" style="cursor: move;" class="picture_uploaded">
    </div>
  <div id="rank-3" class="multibox file">
  <div class="picture_delete"></div>
  <img src="../../images/gallery/thumb/3.jpg" style="cursor: move;" class="picture_uploaded">
  </div>
  </div>
```

(get my photos from database)

Ajax

```
$ (document).ready(function () {

  $('.sortable').sortable();
  $('.sortable').on('sortupdate', function (event,ui) {


    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

    var url = 'inc/sort-gallery.php';
    $.post(url, {data:data}, function(response) {
    })
  })
});
```

And this is my sortable.php

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $siralama);
    $rank=$siralama['rank'];
    foreach ($rank as $key => $id) {
      $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE galeri SET sira = :sirasi WHERE id = :idsi");
      $update = $query->execute(array(
          "sirasi" => $key,
          "idsi" => $id,
      ));
    }
```

Like I told you. Doing a smooth sort with the top 10 photos. it works smoothly. but when the photo is more than 10, the sort is corrupted.

Comment: :(( somebody can help me?

Comment: Anna can you provide a jsfiddle or a working example where one can see the problem?